# MAMP virtualHost does not open file under specified directory

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to set up VirtualHost on my MAMP. I Edited the http-vhost.conf file  like so:

```
    <VirtualHost *:8888>
        DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
        DocumentRoot “/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/factoryPattern/”
        ServerName factory
</VirtualHost>
```

I theory I would expect to type in my browser factory and index file under the fiven directory would open. Instead what I get when I type in Factory in my browser factoryPattern folder that I have to click and then i need to clinc index.php file to view the file content.

I would like if this would of happen automatically by typing Factory...

What am I doing wrong...?

Comment: did you set a `DirectoryIndex` that makes `index.php` a default document for your sites? If not, then if there's no default document, you'd get a browse view instead.

Comment: I would encourage you to avoid *MAMP* and [install Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Mac OS X](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2014/11/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-yosemite/) the native way.

Comment: Awesome post @JasonMcCreary. I didn't want to change to Yosemite because I had so much configured already. Your article should make things a bit easier.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard, awesome. Glad it helped.